# Find similar words within a variable in R

Tags: regex, r, character

Let's say I have a variable that contains the following words

```
ChicKen120
Chicken1.20
Chicken(1.20)
Cow
cow.
cow/
cat
```

1. How do I find similar words that only vary by one or two characters?

I realise that I could do 
`grep("chicken", df$words, ignore.case=T)` to find all words similar to chicken, but it will be tedious to run this through every word, i.e. first chicken, then cow, then cat..

Is there a way to find similar words within the whole column?

2. I want convert similar words to one standard format,

   ```
   chicken(1.20)
   chicken(1.20)
   chicken(1.20)
   cow
   cow
   cow
   cat
   ```

Comment: You haven't defined what "similar" is, and also there is no easy answer to your question.  You will need a special library for this, if it exists.

Comment: use `sub`. `sub("(?i).*(chicken\\(?1\\.?20\\)?|cow).*", '\\1', x)`

Comment: Let's say "similar" is words that contain all the same letters and numbers ([A-z] &[0-9]), ignoring symbols (fullstops, parathesis, slashes).

Answer (score 7):

Concerning your first question, you can try with `adist()`:

```
text <- c("ChicKen120","Chicken1.20","Chicken(1.20)","Cow","cow.", "cow/")
> adist(text)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    0    2    4    9    9    9
#[2,]    2    0    2   10    9   10
#[3,]    4    2    0   12   11   12
#[4,]    9   10   12    0    2    2
#[5,]    9    9   11    2    0    1
#[6,]    9   10   12    2    1    0
```

The matrix elements with 2 or less connect pairs of those six word which differ by at most 2 characters.

More specifically, the pairs of words that are not identical and that differ by at most two characters can be listed with:

```
which(adist(text)<=2 & upper.tri(adist(text)), arr.ind=T)     
#     row col
#[1,]   1   2
#[2,]   2   3
#[3,]   4   5
#[4,]   4   6
#[5,]   5   6
```

Here the logical function `upper.tri()` has been used to select only the upper triangle of the matrix, thereby preventing the double output of pairs (i.e., a repetition in reverse order) and removing the identical pairs on the diagonal.

The words corresponding to the row and column numbers listed above can be retrieved like this:

```
words <- text[which(adist(text)<=2 & upper.tri(adist(text)), arr.ind=T)]
matrix(words,ncol=2)
#     [,1]          [,2]           
#[1,] "ChicKen120"  "Chicken1.20"  
#[2,] "Chicken1.20" "Chicken(1.20)"
#[3,] "Cow"         "cow."         
#[4,] "Cow"         "cow/"         
#[5,] "cow."        "cow/"
```

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around the output. I am writing in thinking that object 1(`ChicKen120`) and object 3(`Chicken(1.20)`) vary by 4 characters, being `K`, `(` , `.`, `)` (capital K, two paranthesis and a fullstop).

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Those are the four differences. Hence the matrix elements [1,3] and [3,1] are equal to 4.

Comment: Would it be possible to return groups of similar words. i.e. the words where differences are less than 4.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to R, how would it possible to return the values rather than row numbers?

Comment: Helps greatly. However, is it possible to only return unique instances. i.e., `Chicken1.20` is repeated twice in the output, is it possible to return just a single vector with each similar word. 
`words = Chicken1.20,  Chicken(1.20), Cow...` For example, it would return all the words except `cat` as cat is the only one that is not similar.

Comment: Hmm....  this this depends a good deal on what you consider a unique instance (paraphrasing Lewis Carroll...). But you could select one column in the output matrix, like `matrix(words,ncol=2)[,1]`. It suspect that this would be close to what you are looking for.

Comment: For example, my approach would be to column bind (`cbind`) the two columns, then run the `unique` function to remove repeats, this would leave a single column with only one occurrence of the similar word.

Comment: If I were to merge to the two columns, then run `unique(words)` to leave only a single instance of each "similar word". For example, looking at the updated df in the original post, I would be left with a single column that contains all of the words except `cat`, as cat is the only one that is not similar to anything else. 

Is there a cleaner approach to my method (listed below)?
[1. Merge two columns.
2. Run `unique` on resulting column.
3. Remaining output is all words except cat, as cat is not similar to any other value.]

Comment: I think I've the solution to that part. Do not run `matrix(words,ncol=2)`, then run `unique(words)`..i'll carry on working on this and update with my progress

Answer (score 1):

Consider a nested gsub that removes all the unwanted special characters and retains the word stems even moving all to lower cases. Below removes forward and back slashes, periods and parentheses (should you need other patterns incorporate into pattern argument and separate with pipe delimiter):

```
df$newvar <- gsub(pattern = '([[:upper:]])', perl = TRUE, 
                  replacement = '\\L\\1', gsub('[/|\\\\|\\.()]','', df$var))
```

From this, use another `gsub()` to handle other needed patterns which you as the user must decide knowing your needs and data. It would be difficult for R to know ahead you want `(1.20)` from a `120` value and `1.20`:

```
df$newvar <- gsub('120','(1.20)', df$newvar)
```

**OUTCOME**

```
    var             newvar
1   ChicKen120      chicken(1.20)
2   Chicken1.20     chicken(1.20)
3   Chicken(1.20)   chicken(1.20)
4   Cow             cow
5   cow.            cow
6   cow/            cow
7   cat             cat
8   cat\            cat                 #<---- ADDED FOR DEMO
```